# Missing 'Comment' property on dlls in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

We are using the comments property for our DLLs.

In Windows XP it will show up in the file properties under "Comments".

In Windows 7 this field has been removed (or I can't find it). Is it possible to show its contents somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326998/what-happend-to-assemblydescription-in-windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the "Comments" property you're looking for in Windows Explorer is now named "File description" ?

Comment: No, description is still the same as it was in XP. Comments was listed under 'other version information'.

Comment: @chris: The Comments column is still there in the alphabetical list that you get with right-click on any column-header and choosing "More...", but doesn't seem to show anything. So either (1) In the Win7 Explorer MS has successfully destroyed it, or (2) It has been renamed. I didn't dare base an answer on the 1st possibility.

Comment: "File description" is what is shown when the cursor hovers over a DLL in Explorer.